# How to get the contact from the CONTENT URI

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I add a custom contact raw to my contacts from my app (like in whatsapp). When I click the custom raw, it open my app. In my viewing activity I check the action and get the content URI from `getIntent().getDataString()`. It gives me this - `content://com.android.contacts/data/10399`.
Now I want to get the contact details from this URI. But when I check my contact list using the following code.

```
void checkContacts(Context context) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.e(TAG, cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID)));
                Log.e(TAG, "** " + cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But i couldn't find any `CONTACT_ID` or `RAW_CONTACT_ID` related to `10399`.
So how do I get the contact detail from this URI?
I don't want to get all the contacts. I want to get the specific contact related to the URI.

Comment: Read my description. Its not about getting all the contacts. I want to get a specific contact from the content URI - `content://com.android.contacts/data/10399`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
String[] projection = {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME 
};

Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
    null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int numberColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
String number = cursor.getString(numberColumnIndex);

int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);

cursor.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! It Worked.. Seems like I'm getting the `ContactsContract.Data._ID`. Its neither the `ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID` or  `ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID`.